# Parse a unix/epoch value as a `TIMESTAMP` in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, optimization, import, timestamp, copy

PostgreSQL's [`COPY` command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-copy.html) is useful to quickly import lots of data, and the data must be in the textual representation for the datatype.

I am importing lots of data, includes a [`timestamp` column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/datatype-datetime.html), but it's stored as ["unix time"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), i.e. seconds since the epoch. I can convert it to [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (e.g. `2010-01-01 00:00:00`, and PostgreSQL accept that for a `timestamp`. It does not accept the raw epoch value integer.

Is it possible to get postgres to accept the epoch integer value and interpret/convert that to a timestamp? That would make my code simpiler (and maybe faster).

This works with `psql`:

```
create temporary table test1 ( v1 timestamp );
copy test1 from stdin ;
Enter data to be copied followed by a newline.
End with a backslash and a period on a line by itself, or an EOF     signal.
>> 2010-01-01 00:00:00
>> \.
COPY 1
```

But these don't:

```
copy test1 from stdin ;
Enter data to be copied followed by a newline.
End with a backslash and a period on a line by itself, or an EOF signal.
>> 946684800
>> \.
ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "946684800"
HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.
CONTEXT:  COPY test1, line 1, column v1: "946684800"
copy test1 from stdin ;
Enter data to be copied followed by a newline.
End with a backslash and a period on a line by itself, or an EOF signal.
>> epoch + 946684800
>> \.
ERROR:  time zone displacement out of range: "epoch + 946684800"
CONTEXT:  COPY test1, line 1, column v1: "epoch + 946684800"
```

The [`to_timestamp` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-formatting.html) is able to accept an 'integer' or the string text of that integer. I can't see an option like this for [`DateStyle` setting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DATESTYLE). I have tried with the column being a `timestamp with time zone` type, with the same results.

I'm currently runing PostgreSQL 10 on Ubuntu Linux, but upgrading to 11 (or 12 soon) is possible if needed.

Answer (score 6):

There is no way to do that with `COPY` alone. You either have to pre-process or post-process the data.

Perhaps `UNLOGGED` tables can make this a little bit faster:

```
/* no WAL logging for better performance */
CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE test1 (v1 double precision);

COPY test1 FROM STDIN;
Enter data to be copied followed by a newline.
End with a backslash and a period on a line by itself, or an EOF signal.
>> 946684800
>> \.

/* this will rewrite the table */
ALTER TABLE test1
   ALTER v1 TYPE timestamp without time zone
      USING (to_timestamp(v1) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC');

/* this will dump the table to the transaction log */
ALTER TABLE test1 SET LOGGED;
```

This will allow you to keep the intermediate manipulations out of the transaction log, which is good for performance.